# Include PNG Image in TexShop

Tags: pdftex, texshop

I am wondering what may be missing from this code. I have stored all the LaTeX files in the same folder  as the png image I'd like to import. The image is called "Signature" and it is saved as such.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\title{Physics Honors Problem Set 1}
\author{Justinian Vladutiu}
\date{September, 2014}
\maketitle

\includegraphics{Signature.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\setlength` command and `[pdftex]` option are both irrelevant. Replacing `Signature.png` with `example-image-a` (included in the `mwe` package) makes this compile correctly. So does it compile if you simply use `Signature` instead of `Signature.png`? If not, what error occurs?

Comment: The error is that it says: File Signature not found. I don't know why this could be so, considering that I put the image in the same file as the rest of the LaTeX stuff.

Comment: Is it in the **same directory as your .tex file** i.e. the document you are trying to compile?

Comment: No. I figured out what the issue was. Apparently the file must be on the desktop or somewhere saved locally because LaTeX takes files stored only on the hard drive. Therefore, saving it in Dropbox, as I had it, but not on the desktop, was the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a not available file

Answer (score 1):

in my case code like this works :

```
\begin{figure}

\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{name.png}
 \caption{what's that}
\label{label}

\end{figure}
```